# Fdisk /dev/sda permission denied

Tags: partitioning, permissions, usb-drive

Hi I've had a look at other questions but the solution doesn't seem to work

I've gone into the command terminal and got root permission using sudo su

I've then viewed my fdisk -l
Which has shown me  /Dev/sda1 /sda2 and /sda3 which is two Microsoft basic data and the Efi system. The usb only has the OS I used to download Linux .

I want to purge the usb drive but it won't view in my Mac so I've put it on my Linux device and tried to use the /dev/sda1 d command but got permission denied

Tried with sudo Infront to but has not worked . Can anyone help me I need that USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the USB disk shows up as `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`, and you want to wipe it out? In that case you are on the right track by using fdisk, but you used the wrong argument. It should have been `/dev/sda` (without the trailing number).

`/dev/sda` is the complete USB disk, which includes the partition table. On your disk, there are three partitions: `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3`. When you want to wipe out your disk using fdisk, you want to delete partitions. So you should use `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: No problem! If my answer got you sorted, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: it worked sorted out about an hour ago. Thank you so much once again.